# I cant got an id from database , and got error a non-numeric value encounteres

Tags: database, laravel, database-connection

I want to get the id to edit the data from database, but when I try to get it , I got an error "A non-numeric value encountered"

This is my file.blade.php
`

```
<tbody>
                          @foreach ($barangs as $item)
                           <tr>
                            <td>{{$item->kode_barang}}</td>
                            <td>{{$item->nama_barang}}</td>
                            <td><a href="{{ url('editbarang'/$item->id)}}" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></a> <span>
                                <a href="" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a>
                            </td>
                          </tr>
                          @endforeach
                        </tbody>`
```

and this is the controller

```
public function data(){

        $barangs = DB::table('barang')->get();
        //return $barangs;
        return view('barang',['barangs'=>$barangs]);
   }
```

I dont know it is, I try to changed into {{ url('editbarang'/(int)$item->id)}} or {{ url('editbarang'/int($item->id))}} and still got error .
Could you help me? Maybe I forgot something?

Thanks :)

Comment: you are trying to divide a string, `'editbarang'`, by anything ... the `/` operator doesn't like strings

Comment: yes, I want to get page with name editbarang/id like that, then I got an error like that, so you have any suggestion of this?

Comment: sorry its my fault, I should have put /into concatenate, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the `/` inside the string and concatenate it to `$item->id`

```
{{ url('editbarang/' . $item->id)}}
```

Comment: Aha, I see, its my fault , I dont put "/" into concatenates , ok thanks, it fixed now :)